# Integral of trigonometric function seems unit-dependent

Tags: trigonometry, definite-integrals

for this problem I have to compute the fraction of a flux within a certain angle range.

The flux distribution in $\phi$ is $I(\phi) = I_0 \cos^2(\phi)$, centred in 0 and spanning the flat angle. The range in which I have to calculate the flux fraction is $20$ degrees, or $0.111\pi$ radiants, in both directions.

The way I would calculate this is the ratio between the two integrals
$\int_{-20º}^{20º} I(\phi)$ and $\int_{-90º}^{90º} I(\phi)$.

Knowing that the integral of $\cos^2(\phi)$ is $\frac{\cos(\phi)\sin(\phi)+\phi}{2}$, that would make for instance the first integral

$I_0  \cos(20)\sin(20)+20$

and the second one $I_0  \cos(90)\sin(90)+90$

Here comes my confusion: the ratio between this two integrals should not depend on the unit I chose, while it obviously differs whether I use degrees or radiants.
What am I missing here? Seems to me that I should use radiants by default, but why would that be so?

Thanks in advance for your replies

Answer (score 1):

In trigonometric functions we use Radians by default. If you use degrees you will have to convert it to Radians.

Generally you still get the right answer, but you'll notice the difference in such cases.